# If a user denies access to the camera in codename one can you find out from code

Tags: android, ios, camera, codenameone

When you open the camera the user is prompted to grant the app permission to access the camera.
Is there any way in Codename one to tell if the user has denied this permission?
With either a callback or some kind of global call?
This specific to iOS but with the recent updates to Android the same question is also relevant there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now built in to the CodenameOne platform - https://www.codenameone.com/blog/switching-on-android-marshmallow-permission-prompts.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently we haven't enabled the Marshmallow permission prompts by default in part due to the lack of an API to indicate that.

We have a standard API for [contacts permissions](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#isContactsPermissionGranted--) which we needed in iOS and most of the API's should be ready for Marshmallow since iOS always had the ability to deny permissions.

But we need to re-think the API's for querying that detail and whether we want them to follow the style of `isContactsPermissionGranted`.

I noticed there is no issue to track the progress of this so [I filed it](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1718).

Comment: I'm not familiar with cross platform frameworks so sorry if this sounds dum but isn't there a way to add a code snippet specifying that this is meant only for a specific platform?

Comment: perhaps a more generic method for checking permisions would be useful?  

Like for example: isPermissionGranted(Display.CAMERA);

That way you could extend it for any type of permission without altering the API.

Comment: You can write native OS code as such: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html however because these API's are implemented in an abstract way you won't get the result for those specific calls and you'd have to implement the entire functionality (e.g. camera capture) natively which is possible but not as easy. Since Codename One is open source it would actually be easier to just contribute a pull request to Codename One than doing it from scratch.